# Redirect HTTPS to HTTPS with NGINX conflicting server name error

Tags: nginx, ssl, redirect

My website will change url, I'm trying to apply a redirect (HTTPS to HTTPS), but I'm getting the following error:

```
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "old-name.example.com" on 0.0.0.0:443, ignored nginx.
```

Here is my nginx config file on /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/myconf.conf:

```
server {
        
            server_name old-name.example.com;
        
            location / {
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS';
                #
                # Custom headers and headers various browsers *should* be OK with but aren't
                #
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range,Authorization,x-auth';
                #
                # Tell client that this pre-flight info is valid for 20 days
                #
    
                [some config....]
            }
        
            listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    
           [ssl config...]
}
        
        
server {
            if ($host = old-name.example.com) {
                return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
            } # managed by Certbot
        
        
                listen 80;
        
                server_name old-name.example.com;
            return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
        
server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name old-name.example.com;
        return 301 $scheme://www.new-name.com$request_uri;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using duplicate server name listening on the same port is senseless, the second server block will never be chosen to handle the request. You probably need something like

```
server {
    server_name www.new-name.com;
    listen 443 ssl;
    ... ssl config for the www.new-name.com
    location / {
        ... serve content
    }
}
server {
    server_name www.new-name.com;
    listen 80;
    return 301 https://www.new-name.com$request_uri;
}
server {
    server_name old-name.example.com;
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    ... ssl config for the old-name.example.com
    return 301 https://www.new-name.com$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: i try to do my redirect with your scheme, and i got the following error: 414 Request-URI Too Large. Ahd the url goes like this:  https://www.old-name.example.com/https:://www.new-name.example.com/http:://www.new-name.example.com and it goes on for a while, what can i do wrong?

Comment: Are your sure you didn't made a typo using `https:://...` instead of `https://...`?

Comment: this is what return 2 looks like:  `return 301 new-name.example.hu$request_uri;,return 301 https://new-name.example.hu$request_uri;`

Comment: Still I don't understand. Do you have two return statements? What for? Is it what I show you to do in my answer?

Comment: Yes, there is one in the example in the second server block and there is one in the example in the third server block.

Comment: Still don't understand. Those are from different server blocks. Both `return` statements should be equal, `return 301 https://www.new-name.com$request_uri;` (or better use 302 for the debugging purposes). Note that 301 redirects are being cached by the browsers, so if you already got one wrong redirect cached, clear the cache or try from the incognito browser window.